# What is the correct phrase for solving mathematical problems?

Tags: phrases, usage, mathematics

While attempting and solving maths problems, do we "Do" those problems?
Is the usage "While doing algebra in high school" the correct phrase to convey that I have been taking a class of algebra and solving problems in algebra? What is the correct phrase, kindly help me out.
(Pardon me if I have been completely incorrect in my usage, English is my second language and I am entirely unsure of how to convey my message in an article)

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but it's bound to have a dissatisfying answer. Terms like _take exams, give exams, sit exams, take courses, solve problems, do homework,_ etc. are  intensely local. Each school, never mind each city, county, region, and country, has its own way of talking about these things. The only way to cope is to listen to those around you and imitate their way of speech. That's what we do anyway, so go ahead.

Comment: "We've been doing algebra today" is fine. But we *solve* problems, algebraic or any other kind.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was unaware of that and had presumed that there existed a certain rule to this, Thank you so much

Comment: Understood, @WeatherVane, thank you!

Comment: _Doing algebra_ seems rather colloquial to me. "While studying algebra" sounds more 'grown-up'.

Answer (score 1):

Those are distinct questions. Working on algebra is not necessarily solving problems; it is quite possibly just studying the textbook or class notes.

Trying to solve a math problem is more specific than just trying to learn a subject, although it is often *part of* learning a subject.

A good word that means "attemping to solve a problem" (like a math problem) is "tackling" the problem.

Note that "tackling" does not imply that the problem is in fact being solved. It means only that there is an *attempt* to solve it.